# Subtracting two datetime.datetime.now().time() objects

Tags: python, datetime, time

I'm trying to build a chronometer with Python, but I'm having trouble subtracting times.

This is what I'm doing:

```
start = datetime.datetime.now().time()
end = datetime.datetime.now().time()
delta = end - start
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

I've looked around and saw some people solving this problem with datetime.combine, but when I try to do it I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'combine'
```

Comment: It's not possible. What if the function takes 10 secs to run and you start at 5 seconds to midnight?

Comment: You can always see how long something takes to run but not with `time()` objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might instead consider using the `time` module, this will return the UNIX time in seconds so you can easily find the difference between two times in seconds, you could then convert this to a time string format if desired.

```
import time
start = time.time()
time.sleep(1)
end = time.time()
delta = end - start
```

Or still using `datetime` you can remove the `.time()` call in your code

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = end - start
```

This returns a timedelta object which has properties such as `.days`, `.seconds`, `.microseconds` which you can use to extract the different time parts of the difference.

Comment: You could do the same with the `datetime` module, just not the way that the OP hoped